# A return function that returns a function in javascript

Tags: javascript

Please i am having an issue with my java script.

```
   start_clock_ws : function(){
            var that = this;
            ..decl


            function init(){
                if(socket.isReady() === true){
                    socket.send({ "time": 1});
                    console.log("clock started");
                }else{
                    console.log("The other guy");
                    console.log("The ready state is",socket.isReady());
                    return that.start_clock(); //Here is my issue
                }
            };   
           function responseMsg(response){
               ..decl  
            }
           this.run = function(){
                console.log("the parent fired");
                setInterval(init, 60000);
            };
            console.log("Its here");
            init();
            this.run();
            this.clock_started = true;
             socket.init({
                onmessage : function(msg){
                    var response = JSON.parse(msg.data);
                    console.log("It fires here first");
                    if (response && response.msg_type === 'time') {

                        responseMsg(response);
                    }
                }
            });

    },
start_clock : function(){
}
```

My issue is with the else above. I checked the value of my isReady() and it was false . I then returned my start_clock. However, when i execute , it returns the `start_clock` and proceeded and run my `this.run`. Shouldn't the `return` above force it to proceed with the `start_clock` leaving the rest part of the code ? Before it was not return , it was just a function call. I then added the return hoping it would work. Also while debugging. I noticed my `socket.onmessage` function is being called multiple times and due to ws request. I then took it to the extreme below the `run` .

Please help or explanation would be appreciated. Its quite new to me and is having difficulty understanding the problem.

Comment: When your inner function returns a value, your parent function is suppose to catch it. This will not return automatically. You will have to check the returned value and return manually.

Comment: @Rajesh pls can you give example ?

Comment: Below answer given by @alexqoliveira is an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this when you call the init function:

```
if(init())
{
    return;
}
```

If the function returns int value, it is because you are returning a function and the code has to stop. But if no return value (undefined), the code will continue.

I hope ist help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// Check if clock_started and if not then run following code.
if(!init()){
    this.run();
    this.clock_started = true;
    socket.init({
        onmessage : function(msg){
            var response = JSON.parse(msg.data);
            console.log("It fires here first");
            if (response && response.msg_type === 'time') {
                responseMsg(response);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Also

```
function init(){
    if(socket.isReady() === true){
        socket.send({ "time": 1});
        console.log("clock started");

        return false; 
    }else{
        console.log("The other guy");
        console.log("The ready state is",socket.isReady());
        return that.start_clock(); //Here is my issue
    }
};
```

I have created a simple [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eu1wyfmd/) for explanation purpose.

#### Explanation of issue

`Return` is used to return a value to the calling function. You have to receive this value and process it accordingly. In your code, you are calling a function but there is no check for return value, hence it proceeds.

#### Code

```js
function welcome(name){
 console.log("Hello " + name);
}

function permission(returnValue){
    var str = returnValue?"You may proceed.":"You may not.";
    console.log(str);
 return returnValue
}

function proceed(){
 console.log("Proceeding to next task.")
}

function run1(){
 welcome('foo');
    permission(false);
    proceed();
}

function run2(){
 welcome('foo');
    if(permission(false))
     proceed()
    else
        console.log("Permission denied.");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="run1()">Not Checking return value</button>
<button onclick="run2()">Checking return value</button>
```